# How to know the checkboxlist items (from dynamically) are checked or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i create a 2 chekboxlist in asp.net c#, this chek box list's list items are filled from database(dynamically) then i want to check the these check box lists are checked or not? please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this code

```
IEnumerable<int> allChecked = (from item in chkBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>() 
                               where item.Selected 
                               select int.Parse(item.Value));
```

Comment: You can append this answer to your previous answer so that reader can have two alternative in one answer......

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    String values = "";
    for (int i=0; i< cbl.Items.Count; i++)
    {
            if(cbl.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                    values += cbl.Items[i].Value + ",";
            }
    }

    values = values.TrimEnd(',');
```

Or you can use this code (Linq)

```
    IEnumerable<int> allChecked = (from item in chkBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>() 
                               where item.Selected 
                               select int.Parse(item.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string ids=string.Empty;

foreach (ListItem item in checkboxlist1.Items)
        { 
            if(item.Selected)
ids+=item.Value+",";
        }

ids=ids.Trim(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectedIndex` to check whether checklist is checked or not:

```
if( ckl.SelectedIndex != -1 )
{
// Do Something
}
```